# Menu's dropdown on Chart is being offset

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, chakra-ui, foreignobject

I'm adding a `chakra-ui` menu dropdown button to a chart (from `react-financial-charts`, which is a library built over `svg`).

For some reason, when I click on the menu, there will be whitespace between the button and the dropdown menu. This only happens when I put the menu onto the chart. If I have the menu standalone in the browser, it'll work as expected.

[image]

This is the menu code:

```
function TestMenu() {
  return (
    <g className="react-financial-charts-enable-interaction">
      <foreignObject
        x={30}
        y={30}
        width={"100%"}
        height={"100%"}
        style={{ overflow: "auto" }}
      >
        <Menu>
          <MenuButton as={Button} rightIcon={<ChevronDownIcon />}>
            Actions
          </MenuButton>
          <MenuList>
            <MenuItem>Download</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>Create a Copy</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>Mark as Draft</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>Delete</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>Attend a Workshop</MenuItem>
          </MenuList>
        </Menu>
      </foreignObject>
    </g>
  );
}
```

This is the full codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-haze-3mz2c?file=/src/BasicLineSeries.tsx:511-1199

**EDIT**

If I remove `x={0}` and `y={0}` from `foreignObject` and include `style={{ marginTop: "30px", marginLeft: "30px" }}` into `MenuButton` instead, as suggested by one of the answers, this will solve the problem *only if* the chart is at the top of the page. Otherwise, if there is a `div` before the chart, then this will occur:

[image]

and here's the full codesandbox for that:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-pare-c5rxu?file=/src/BasicLineSeries.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

According to the menu list position problem, you can make use of [Portal](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/portal) to move the entire list options to the bottom of the DOM so that its style will not be affected by any style/component inside the Chart.

```js
...
<Menu>
  <MenuButton
    as={Button}
    rightIcon={<ChevronDownIcon />}
    transition="all 0.001s"
    borderRadius="md"
    borderWidth="0px"
    _hover={{ bg: "gray.400" }}
    _expanded={{ bg: "blue.400" }}
    _focus={{ boxShadow: "none" }}
    style={{ marginTop: "30px", marginLeft: "30px" }} // better move the style to css file 
  >
    Actions
  </MenuButton>
  <Portal>
    <MenuList zIndex={10}>
      <MenuItem>Download</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>Create a Copy</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>Mark as Draft</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>Delete</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>Attend a Workshop</MenuItem>
    </MenuList>
  </Portal>
</Menu>
...
```

The [Updated Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-cohen-8troh?file=/src/BasicLineSeries.tsx)

---

The white space is triggered by the `foreignObject`'s `x` and `y` where the `MenuList` is respecting the space specified in `foreignObject`. (You can try to increase x and y, you will see a larger gap between the button and menu list)

To solve the problem, you can remove the `x` and `y` and apply the margin on `MenuButton`

```js
...
<foreignObject
  width={"100%"}
  height={"100%"}
  style={{ overflow: "auto" }}
>
  <Menu>
    <MenuButton
      as={Button}
      rightIcon={<ChevronDownIcon />}
      transition="all 0.001s"
      borderRadius="md"
      borderWidth="0px"
      _hover={{ bg: "gray.400" }}
      _expanded={{ bg: "blue.400" }}
      _focus={{ boxShadow: "none" }}
      style={{ marginTop: "30px", marginLeft: "30px" }} // better move the style to css file
    >
      Actions
    </MenuButton>
    <MenuList>
      <MenuItem>Download</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>Create a Copy</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>Mark as Draft</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>Delete</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>Attend a Workshop</MenuItem>
    </MenuList>
  </Menu>
</foreignObject>
...
```

Here is [the modified codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-cori-r14o0?file=/src/BasicLineSeries.tsx)

Comment: That didn't solve the general problem. Have a look at this codesandbox where I added a div before the chart: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-pare-c5rxu?file=/src/BasicLineSeries.tsx --- I've updated my OP to reflect this new information.

Comment: Please check the updated answer. If it still cannot solve your problem, I will remove my answer to let other know it is still not resolved.

Comment: Perfect. I have a followup question here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68533518/position-a-menu-to-the-right-of-chart